# MSDN Windows 10 Workspace functions

Tags: winapi, windows-10

I can't find the new windows 10 workspace functions.

I need this because Im trying to figure out the windows on the current monitor. My old code works for getting all windows on current monitor. But now I need to filter futher by current workspace.

Do you know where the workspace functions are on MSDN? I cant find them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These functions aren't new. These date from Windows 2000 at least, if not before. The internal Win32 name for this functionality is *desktops*. The documentation is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687098.aspx

What's new is that the Windows 10 shell finally starts to use this functionality. But there are other third party tools that allow users to create virtual desktops. So this has been an issue for a long time.

Comment: Thanks @David very much!! :)